# Separate tax config for promotions

Tags: checkout, shopping-cart-price-rules, tax, promotions

I have an issue with a Magento store where my client would like to create more advanced configurations for checkout promotions.

Default magento stacks all promotions in priority and calculates on at a time.
Is it possible to make it so that every promotion has it's own calculation from the start?

So in short:

- Apply rules separately instead of priority based
- Configure which rules should be applied on incl. and excl. tax prices.

Let me give an example:

- Total price (excl) = € 100,-
- Tax (21%) = € 21,-
- Promotion rule 1 (discount 30% incl tax) = (100 + 21) * 30% = € -36,30
- Promotion rule 2 (discount 2% excl tax) = 100 * 2% = € -2,-
- Final price = 100 - 36,30 - 2 + 21 = € 82,-